# Binary Search Closest Value c#

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search

i am using this binary search algorithm to find items in my array. I am trying to make it so when i search for a value which doesn't appear in the array my program tells me, and it also reveals where the closest items are

Example Array: (4, 6, 7, 8, 9)
Search for 5
Result 6, 7.

Every time i search for something which isn't an element within my array it returns 0, or -1. Can someone help me out, thanks?

```
  public static double BinarySearch(double[] a, double item)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last = a.Length - 1;
        do
        {
            int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
            if (item > a[mid])
                first = mid + 1;
            else
                last = mid - 1;
            if (a[mid] == item)
                return mid;
        } while (first <= last);       
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: please don't link images here, include your code as text in the question

Comment: fixed, sorry, new to this

Comment: When you say "my program tells me, and it also reveals where the closest items are", how do you want your program to do this?  i.e. should the function return where the closest item is whilst the simply doing a `Debug.WriteLine` to say there are no matches, are you happy to change the return type to something that can carry both bits of information, or do you want a negative of the closest position returned where it's not found, whilst the positive position is returned where it is?

Comment: Are you aware that .NET already has a BinarySearch implementation, named `Array.BinarySearch` (and also `List<T>.BinarySearch`)?  It doesn't immediately tell you which is the closer item, only which two items it falls between, but it would be pretty easy to use that return value to find your closest item.

Comment: If i can change the return type to help me with my problem, then that would be great. What would i need to do to find the closest elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you would declare "mid" outside the loop and return it ? Instead of -1 ?

When your array is sorted and the searched value is not found, you will get a mid result pointing to the lower value in the array closest to your search value. The element above your search value is contained in a[mid+1]. Small change:

```
public static double BinarySearch(double[] a, double item)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = a.Length - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    do
    {
        mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
        if (item > a[mid])
            first = mid + 1;
        else
            last = mid - 1;
        if (a[mid] == item)
            return mid;
    } while (first <= last);
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: This is great, it reveals where abouts within the array the element is, so i can work out the higher and lower from that. But how would i display that the element isn't within the array? because the search just finds the closest elements and reveals the index. Thanks 
(sorry, i'm fairly new to c#)

Comment: You do have access to your array, so test if (a[index]==item) afterward.